# How to Fix CSS3 PIE Box-Shadow Issue in IE8

Tags: css, css3pie

Im new with CSS3 PIE. I just wanna ask how can i make the sidebar display correctly?

The site is in `http://204.197.252.143/~themainr/comments/`

My code to the side bar is:

```
#secondary{
background-color:#EEEEEE;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top:0px!important;
padding-right:6px!important;

overflow:none;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
box-shadow: -7px 0px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
behavior: url('http://204.197.252.143/~themainr/wp-content/themes/themainreport/pie/PIE.htc');
}
```

If you refresh the site, there are instances that the sidebar will look like this:
 [image]

**Q: How can I fix this CSS3 PIE Box-Shadow Issue in IE8.**

Comment: Is the issue the white line, the sidebar is not in the correct location, the `Contact | Become A Member | Multi-User` not in the correct location? Can you be more specific? What do you want it to look like instead?

Comment: Also, what version of which browser are you using?

Comment: @eggy: I am using ie10 but I view it with IE8view & standards functionality of the IE10. 

Did you see the error with your browser in IE before I removed the box-shadow?

Thanks BTW for you comment however the client requested to remove the shadow. To remove the hassle.

Comment: @Jed You did not state any query. Can you please ask a proper question like "How do I remove box-shadow?" or "Why is CSS3 PIE not working for me when I use it on an element?".
If you ask it we will answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shadow is not working with Ie 8 below but I can suggest to you an idea crop background image of your sidebar and you will include the background and set it as background in the css of your Ie8 and below :-)